# Why isn't android studio not producing a launcher upon release?

Tags: java, android, apk, signed, app-launcher

I am a newbie to Android Development and I'd thought I'd start out with a game. Anyway it works running on my device through Android studio (version 3.5) in debug mode. But when I change the build environment to release and produce a signed apk when it installs it doesn't produce a launcher (shortcut) on the device.

It is listed in APPS in settings on the device but not through the all apps interface.

Android studio gives me the following version information....
"Android Studio 3.5
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 9, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64"

Thanking you in advance,
Jonathan.

Sorry about neglecting the manifest file.... here it is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Game"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />


        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: add both `AndoidManifest.xml` please (this would be the only reason I could think of).

Comment: Can you post your manifest file content?